# Search for a pattern in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a simple way to find all relevant elements in NumPy array according to some pattern?

For example, consider the following array:

```
a = array(['zzzz', 'zzzd', 'zzdd', 'zddd', 'dddn', 'ddnz', 'dnzn', 'nznz',
       'znzn', 'nznd', 'zndd', 'nddd', 'ddnn', 'dnnn', 'nnnz', 'nnzn',
       'nznn', 'znnn', 'nnnn', 'nnnd', 'nndd', 'dddz', 'ddzn', 'dznn',
       'znnz', 'nnzz', 'nzzz', 'zzzn', 'zznn', 'dddd', 'dnnd'], dtype=object)
```

And I need to to find all combinations which contain '**dd'.

I basically need a function, which receives the array as input and returns a smaller array with all relevant elements:

```
>> b = func(a, pattern='**dd')
>> b = array(['zzdd', 'zddd', 'zndd', 'nddd', 'nndd', 'dddd'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: `"**dd"` isn't the regex you need. Maybe you mean wildcard? In which case `fnmatch` is your solution. But write `"??dd"`

Comment: Aside: in many cases (not all, but probably most) when you're working with strings in numpy arrays you're generally better off working with a plain list -- even if you then convert back into an ndarray -- or a pandas.Series.  Whenever you find yourself using `dtype=object` ndarrays you should ask yourself if you've taken a wrong turn.

Comment: @DSM, you are absolutely right about the usage of numpy arrays here. I'm working with Pandas data frames and one of my column contains various combinations of four letters. I simply extracted this one column just to demonstrate the problem I have at hand.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre, you are right, I do need to use wildcard here. Thanks!

Comment: @ArnoldKlein: ah, there are simpler ways to do it in pandas, then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since it turns out you're actually working with pandas, there are simpler ways to do it at the Series level instead of just an ndarray, using the [vectorized string operations](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html):

```
In [32]: s = pd.Series(['zzzz', 'zzzd', 'zzdd', 'zddd', 'dddn', 'ddnz', 'dnzn', 'nznz',
    ...:        'znzn', 'nznd', 'zndd', 'nddd', 'ddnn', 'dnnn', 'nnnz', 'nnzn',
    ...:        'nznn', 'znnn', 'nnnn', 'nnnd', 'nndd', 'dddz', 'ddzn', 'dznn',
    ...:        'znnz', 'nnzz', 'nzzz', 'zzzn', 'zznn', 'dddd', 'dnnd'])

In [33]: s[s.str.endswith("dd")]
Out[33]: 
2     zzdd
3     zddd
10    zndd
11    nddd
20    nndd
29    dddd
dtype: object
```

which produces a Series, or if you really insist on an ndarray:

```
In [34]: s[s.str.endswith("dd")].values
Out[34]: array(['zzdd', 'zddd', 'zndd', 'nddd', 'nndd', 'dddd'], dtype=object)
```

You can also use regular expressions, if you prefer:

```
In [49]: s[s.str.match(".*dd$")]
Out[49]: 
2     zzdd
3     zddd
10    zndd
11    nddd
20    nndd
29    dddd
dtype: object
```

Comment: That NumPy char module has [`startswith`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.startswith.html), just not something like `endswith` :)

Comment: @Divakar: FWIW I was quite impressed you pulled it off. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach using [`numpy.core.defchararray.rfind`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.rfind.html) to get us the last index of a match and then we check if that index is 2 minus the length of each string. Now, the length of each string is `4` here, so we would look for the last indices that are `4 - 2 = 2`.

Thus, an implementation would be -

```
a[np.core.defchararray.rfind(a.astype(str),'dd')==2]
```

---

If the strings are not of equal lengths, we need to get the lengths, subtract `2` and then compare -

```
len_sub = np.array(list(map(len,a)))-len('dd')
a[np.core.defchararray.rfind(a.astype(str),'dd')==len_sub]
```

To test this out, let's add a longer string ending with `dd` at the end of the given sample -

```
In [121]: a = np.append(a,'ewqjejwqjedd')

In [122]: len_sub = np.array(list(map(len,a)))-len('dd')

In [123]: a[np.core.defchararray.rfind(a.astype(str),'dd')==len_sub]
Out[123]: array(['zzdd', 'zddd', 'zndd', 'nddd', 'nndd', 'dddd',\
                 'ewqjejwqjedd'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a `numpy` specialist. However, I understand that you want to create a filtered `numpy` array, not a standard python array, and converting from python array to `numpy` array takes time and memory, so bad option.

Not sure that you *mean* regex, but rather *wildcard*, in which case the correct choice is `fnmatch` module with `??dd` pattern (any 2 chars + `dd` in the end)

(alternate solution would involve `re.match()` with `..dd$` as a pattern).

I would compute the indices matching your criteria, then would use `take` to extract a sublist:

```
from numpy import array
import fnmatch

a = array(['zzzz', 'zzzd', 'zzdd', 'zddd', 'dddn', 'ddnz', 'dnzn', 'nznz',
       'znzn', 'nznd', 'zndd', 'nddd', 'ddnn', 'dnnn', 'nnnz', 'nnzn',
       'nznn', 'znnn', 'nnnn', 'nnnd', 'nndd', 'dddz', 'ddzn', 'dznn',
       'znnz', 'nnzz', 'nzzz', 'zzzn', 'zznn', 'dddd', 'dnnd'], dtype=object)

def func(ar,pattern):
    indices = [i for i,x in enumerate(ar) if fnmatch.fnmatch(x,pattern)]
    return ar.take(indices)

print(func(a,"??dd"))
```

result:

```
['zzdd' 'zddd' 'zndd' 'nddd' 'nndd' 'dddd']
```

regex version (same result in the end of course):

```
from numpy import array
import re

def func(ar,pattern):
    indices = [i for i,x in enumerate(ar) if re.match(pattern,x)]
    return ar.take(indices)

print(func(a,"..dd$"))
```

Comment: Interesting that this seems to only take 4x longer than the `numpy` solution from Divakar yet uses a list comprehension. This is much simpler to follow, I guess it's better to stick to readability for this problem :)

Comment: I tried to create a generator comprehension but `take` wouldn't let me. Yes, the pure numpy answers are very complex yet faster. I guess that `numpy` isn't done to handle/filter string data.

Answer (score 1):

```
import fnmatch
import numpy as np
a = ['zzzz', 'zzzd', 'zzdd', 'zddd', 'dddn', 'ddnz', 'dnzn', 'nznz',
       'znzn', 'nznd', 'zndd', 'nddd', 'ddnn', 'dnnn', 'nnnz', 'nnzn',
       'nznn', 'znnn', 'nnnn', 'nnnd', 'nndd', 'dddz', 'ddzn', 'dznn',
       'znnz', 'nnzz', 'nzzz', 'zzzn', 'zznn', 'dddd', 'dnnd']


b=[]
for item in a:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(item, "z*dd"):
        b.append(item)
print b
```

output

```
['zzdd', 'zddd', 'zndd']
```

Answer (score -1):

Python has a built in function named `.endswith()`. The clue is in the name, it finds any value in a string that ends with the value in the brackets. To do this in your case however you could do the following:

```
i = 0
while i < len(a) :
   if a[i].endswith("dd") :
      print(a[i])
   i += 1
```

Comment: This doesn't use `numpy`

Comment: Also, the expected output contains items with `ddd`.

Comment: He didn't say he needs an answer which *uses* numpy, only that he has data* in a numpy array*. It's not the best solution, of course, but vOv

Comment: @z0rberg's But still, it doesn't return the right output, and the question says "I basically need a function, which receives the array as input and returns a smaller **array**"

Comment: That's true. I wasn't commenting on that. Maybe I was too nitpicky. Sorry.